# Using Glide 4.x with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

I'm surprised I cannot find such a simple thing as how to use Glide, probably **the** most used image library on Android with Kotlin.  Glide's documentation for requestOptions shows this simple code:

```
val requestOptions = RequestOptions().error(R.drawable.error)

Glide.with(context)
    .apply(requestOptions)
    .load(myUrl)
    .into(myView)
```

but it appears Kotlin's apply method is conflicting with Glides apply.  I'm getting a "Type Mismatch" error on my requestOptions parameter.  What's the solution for this? And why isn't this clearly marked in Glides documentation?

Comment: As César shows, order counts. I had put the apply before the load, once I put them into the correct order it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke the apply function of the RequestBuilder from glide. Just change the order and call *load()* first.

```
val requestOptions = RequestOptions().error(R.drawable.error)

Glide.with(context)
    .load(myUrl)
    .apply(requestOptions)
    .into(myView)
```